# Ionic - $ionicLoading does not open

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic application in which I am facing the issue that `$ionicLoading` does not open. There is more posts related to my issue in `stackoverflow` with accepted answers. But unfortunately nothing is working for me.

**Code Snippet:**

***save-all.html***

```
<ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">E-sign</h1>
    </ion-header-bar> 

        <ion-content style="overflow: scroll;" padding="true">

        <div  style="margin-left:15%;margin-right:15%;">
          <button class="button icon-left ion-ios-download button-block button-positive" ng-click="saveAll()">Save</button>
        </div>

         <div  style="margin-left:15%;margin-right:15%;">
          <button class="button  icon-left ion-close-circled  button-block button-assertive" ng-click="clearAll()">Clear All</button>
        </div>

        </div>

    </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

***document.controller.js***

```
angular.module( 'starter.controllers' ).controller( 'EsignCtrl',
    function( $scope, $ionicModal, $ionicLoading, InvoiceService, Response, $stateParams, $cordovaSQLite ) {

        $scope.show    = function() {
            $ionicLoading.show( { template : 'Loading...' } );
        };
        $scope.hide    = function() {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        };
        $scope.saveAll = function() {
            $scope.show(); // Not firing 
            ......
            ......
            ......
            $scope.hide();
        }
    }
```

**Update :**

It is working if I change the ng-click funtion to `show()` in HTML and remove the  `$scope.show()` inside `saveAll()` function and paste it inside `show()` function just after the `$ionicLoading.show()` ,in controller . But I am just confused how this is working.

Please help me finding the solution.

Thanks in Advanced

Comment: post the exact error in console

Comment: I'm compiling and running in Xcode . But console does not show any error .

Comment: is it working in web/android?

Comment: I think because `$scope.show` and `$scope.hide` are in the same function you will never see the loading screen. Try to wrap the `$scope.hide` in a `$timeout` to test it!

Comment: There is a `</div>` too much...

Comment: It is working if I modify the change the ng-click funtion to `show()` in HTML and removing `$scope.show()` inside `saveAll()`  function and paste it inside `show()`function just after the `$ionicLoading.show()` ,in controller . But I don't know why .